# Enable port forwarding with c#

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I use a basic application that enables me to send a file over a tcp connection over the internet to a different computer. The way I managed to do that was to configure the router at my house and office to port forward all incoming traffic from port X to the corresponding computer. I am in a new office now and things work different in here.

There is a main router where all the offices may connect to. I connect my router to that router in order to have my own private network. I still want to be able to use my small application that I created in order to sync the files from my home computer and office computer. The only problem is that I dont have access to the main router therefore I may not open any ports in order to make my program work. I am new to networking so it will be nice if someone can point me to the right direction of how can I solve this. I think I have to let the router know to send all the traffic from port x to my computer. Moreover there are several routers so I dont know if it is possible. I think it should be possible because I am able to connect to my office computer via log me in for example.

It sill be nice if I can still use TCP protocols instead of a p2p since I already have all the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice page that talks about this in [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx).  I will work on it... I am not sure if it works with the tcp protocol.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to connect from your office to your home computer. In this scenario, you have to setup port forwarding on your personal router (which you have already done!). If you connect from your home to the office, you will need to configure every intermediate office router (which your boss probably won't like).

In order to connect to your home network, I would look into setting up DDNS through someone like DynDNS. This will allow you to connect to me.example.com from wherever and have it resolve to your home address even when it changes IP addresses.